# Django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Tags: python, mysql, django, apscheduler

I'm using `apschduler` to call a task every 2hs, in this task it will read data from mysql db.

But after `mysql's default wait_timeout 28800s`, it always raise `Django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`

According from doc [MySQL server has gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html), I think it should be child process issue.

But I still can't solve this problem

`main.py`

```py
import sys, os
import django
import logging
import datetime
import argparse

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'src'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'data_model'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-d', '--execute_dir', type=str,
                    help='exe_dir',
                    default=BASE_DIR)
    args = ap.parse_args()
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(args.execute_dir, "conf"))
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_settings")
    django.setup()

    from auto_management_v2 import auto_manage
    from baseApscheduler import baseScheduler

    scheduler = baseScheduler.scheduler

    scheduler.add_job(
        func=auto_manage,
        trigger='interval',
        hours=2,
        start_date=(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        id='auto_manage',
        jobstore='default',
        replace_existing=True)

    scheduler.start()
```

`baseApscheduler.py`

```py
import logging

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.memory import MemoryJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_ERROR, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED


from django.conf import settings
from utils import sendEmail


logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    filename=settings.AUTO_MANAGEMENT_FILE_NAME,
    filemode='a')


def event_listener(event):
    if event.exception:
        print("task failed！")
        info = '''
        time：{}，
        task_name: {},
        fail_reason: {}
        '''.format(str(event.scheduled_run_time), str(event.job_id), str(event.exception))
        sendEmail(message=info, subject='task failed')
    else:
        print(event.job_id + "task successed！")


class BaseScheduler():

    def __init__(self):
        self.executors = {
            'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(10),
            'processPool': ProcessPoolExecutor(3)
        }

        self.jobstores = {
            'default': MemoryJobStore(),
        }

        self.scheduler = BlockingScheduler(
            jobstores=self.jobstores, executors=self.executors)
        self.scheduler._logger = logging
        self.scheduler.add_listener(
            event_listener,
            EVENT_JOB_ERROR | EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED)


baseScheduler = BaseScheduler()
```

`auto_management_v2.py`

```py
import logging
import datetime
import json
import requests
import urllib
import asyncio

from django.db.utils import OperationalError


from django.conf import settings
django.db.connections.close_all()  # try to close old connection here
from data_model.models import SmbAmmFilter, SmbAmmRule, SmbAmmCampaignFbRule, SmbAmmRuleCampaign


info_logger = logging.getLogger('auto_manage_info')


class AutoManagementServiceV2(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.plan_lists = SmbAmmRuleCampaign.objects.filter(status=1)  
        self.chunk_size = 50 # 

    def run(self):
        new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.iter_plans = (
            self.plan_lists[i:i + self.chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(self.plan_lists), self.chunk_size)
        )
        asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)

        for chunk_plans in self.iter_plans:
            task_list = [
                asyncio.ensure_future(self._handle_campaign_data(campaign_plan)) for campaign_plan in chunk_plans
            ]
            new_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*task_list))


def auto_manage():
    AutoManagementServiceV2().run()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    auto_manage()
```

As ablove codes showed, I think i've close the mysql connection in my task, and hope it do a reconnection work, but always failed..

How can i reconnect to db ervery time I run my task correctly?

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved after adding `django.db.connections.close_all()` in my task `auto_manage`

```py
def auto_manage():
    django.db.connections.close_all()
    AutoManagementServiceV2().run()
```